# How to change wordpress blog password implemented in cakephp site

Tags: php, wordpress, cakephp-2.0

I have integrated a wordpress blog with a cakephp site, and the functionality is when I login on my main site I automatically get logged in my wordpress blog.

But I am having a problem, in the wordpress login process the password is updated in on the cake php site, how to update the  password in the wordpress database when it gets changed on main cakephp site

So please help me regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a action in controller, where you can update the password whenever you change the blog setting in admin area.
If you need more help, Please let me know.